# how to disprove a biconditional logic statement (logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If given a biconditional logic statement.
How can one disprove that statement.
Also how to do it without using a Truth-Table!

Now I know that one can disprove via a counter-example.

But would you need to convert the biconditional to an equivalence statement first?

Hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using common identities, which you can easily verify using a truth table, we have:

$$p \iff q \equiv (p \Rightarrow q) \land (q \Rightarrow p)$$
$$\neg(p \land q) \equiv \neg p \lor \neg q$$
$$\neg(p\Rightarrow q) \equiv p \land \neg q$$

where $\equiv$ means that both logical statements are logically equivalent (i.e. they have the same truth values)

Now, using the three rules above, in the listed order, we have:

$$\neg(p \iff q) \equiv \neg( (p \Rightarrow q) \land (q \Rightarrow p))$$
$$\equiv \neg(p \Rightarrow q) \lor \neg(q \Rightarrow p)$$
$$\equiv (p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \neg p)$$

So we see, that it suffices to show that there are $2$ options to make sure $p \iff q$ is false:

1) $p$ must be true and $q$ must be false

2) $p$ must be false and $q$ must be true

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we have a statement of the form

$$\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$$

that we want to disprove. This is logically equivalent to:

$$(\phi \to \psi) \wedge (\psi \to \phi)$$

This shows us how we can disprove our statement: by demonstrating that *either* $\phi \to \psi $ is false *or* that $\psi \to \phi$ is false.

We can demonstrate that $\phi \to \psi $ is false by showing that $\phi$ holds and $\psi$ does not hold; similarly we demonstrate that $\psi \to \phi $ is false by showing that $\psi$ holds and not $\phi$. Either demonstration will refute the biconditional.

This becomes more challenging when, for some biconditional statements, we aren't able to refute the statement by giving just one of the demonstrations above. Sometimes we have to show that, even though we can't demonstrate *which* of $\phi \to \psi$ and $\psi \to \phi$ is false, we can demonstrate that at least one of them is.

For example, suppose we are trying to refute $P \leftrightarrow \neg P$, knowing nothing about the truth-value of $P$. In this case, since we don't know $P$'s truth-value we can't simply demonstrate that $P$ is true and $\neg P$ is false (to refute $P \to \neg P$), nor can we demonstrate that $\neg P$ is true and $P$ is false (to refute $\neg P \to P$).

But we can say that: if $P$ is true, $P \to \neg P$ is refuted; and if $P$ is false, $\neg P \to P$. So no matter the truth-value of $P$, one of the conditionals must fail, and hence the biconditional is refuted.

Answer (score 0):

Use: $\neg [A\iff B] \equiv [A \land \neg B] \lor [B \land \neg A]$